# How to Integrate the data received in the mobile device with the built in calendar

Tags: android

I am using Android3 CalendarView. I have data such as birthdays, meeting requests each on particular dates.

How to add this data to the built in CalendarView?
Has anyone have the code for this? Please help me.

Comment: how you want to add? give little explanation?

Comment: give some more explanation to me

Comment: Like in Our calendar in mobile we add new reminders, events right.In the same way i want to add the event containing event title, event decription, start time, endtime.

Comment: ok see this link my previous answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846746/put-reminder-in-real-calendar-on-the-phone/6846964#6846964

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Google APIs Client Library for Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) to update the user's Google Calendar.