# Android Calender reminder event issue

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

hello everyone I am a newbie here but I dont care if you people like it or not......... but I do not understand the way this site work.................

If I ask any question that has already been asked i get negative points..... and luckily if I find something useful.. the problem is then... I can not add my comments to that post to clarify the answer for me... for instance i found the following link useful for me

[Put reminder in real calendar on the phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846746/put-reminder-in-real-calendar-on-the-phone)

In that code the user have used the following line

```
Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(this) + "events");
```

I don't understand what should I do because Uri.parse() takes a string argument but here he uses an activity as a argument in

> getCalendarUriBase(Activity act)

I would not have asked this question if I would've allowed to add my comments into that post

I hope you can understand the my point....
and for full code please visit the above link

Comment: getCalendarUriBase(Activity act) have you checked the code in the link. there is method that takes activity context as the parameter. Hence getCalendarUriBase(this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is strange that you didn't understand that answer.

getCalendarUriBase returns a String, its implementation is in that answer.

I copypaste it here for you

```
private String getCalendarUriBase(Activity act) {

                String calendarUriBase = null;
                Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
                Cursor managedCursor = null;
                try {
                    managedCursor = act.managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                if (managedCursor != null) {
                    calendarUriBase = "content://calendar/";
                } else {
                    calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
                    try {
                        managedCursor = act.managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    if (managedCursor != null) {
                        calendarUriBase = "content://com.android.calendar/";
                    }
                }
                return calendarUriBase;
```

Comment: can you help me with this statement ....(epoch = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a").parse(date + " " + time).getTime();)... how should i use date and time? because i have 5 values (day, month, year, hour and minute) all int how can i use these 5 int values instead of date and time mentioned in the statement?

Answer (score 0):

imho,

```
getCalendarUriBase(this) + "events"
=
getCalendarUriBase(this).toString() + "events"
```

String concatenation?